# getchar() is not reading spaces when creating string array?

Tags: c, getchar

I am trying to create a reversed string using getchar() to first read a string in array format. I did not write the reversing part yet. The code works for any strings without space.
Ex. "HelloWorld!" will output "HelloWorld!" but "Hello World!" will only output "Hello".

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main() 
{
    char temp;
    char my_strg[MAX_SIZE];
    int length;

    printf("Please insert the string you want to reverse: ");
    scanf("%s", my_strg);

    while((temp = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        my_strg[length] = temp;
        length++;
    } 

    printf("%s\n", my_strg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `length` is uninitialized, so `my_strg[length]` is likely to be out of bounds.

Comment: Is the `scanf` call left over from an earlier version of the code and you forgot to remove it?

Comment: You use scanf to read the first string (up to whitespace), and then you iterate over the rest of the input, ....why?  Assuming you did initialize length to zero, you would now be overwriting the string read by scanf.  Since you did not initialize length, this is just UB, but even if you did it's not at all clear why you're doing this.

Comment: Initialize `int length = 0;`, get rid of `scanf("%s", my_strg);` (it is superfluous) , change to `while(length < MAX_SIZE - 1 && (temp = getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF)` add `my_strg[length] = 0;` before `printf("%s\n", my_strg);` to *nul-terminate*. (or in the alternative initialize `char my_strg[MAX_SIZE] = "";`)

Comment: Bonus, replace `printf("%s\n", my_strg);` with `puts(my_strg);` -- the compiler will optimize that for your, but making it explicit shows an understanding of basic tools.

Comment: In addition to what @DavidC.Rankin wrote, `char temp;` should be replaced with `int temp;` because the value `EOF` might not fit in a `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has **undefined behaviour**, since you are attempting to access an element of an array, `my_strg[length]` with an **unitialized** value of `length`.

To fix this, move your declaration of `length` to *after* the `scanf` call and initialize it to the length of the string that `scanf` reads:

```c
scanf("%s", my_strg);
size_t length = strlen(my_strg);
```

Alternatively, drop the `scanf` call completely and initialize `length` to zero:

```c
    char my_strg[MAX_SIZE] = { 0, }; // Note: make sure you ALSO initialize your array!!
    printf("Please insert the string you want to reverse: ");
    size_t length = 0;
    while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n') {
    //..
```

Note: If you (for some reason) don't want to initialize your entire array to zeros (as the first line in my second code block will do), then make sure to add a zero (`nul`) character at the end of the string, before printing it (or doing anything else with it). You could simply add this line *after* the `while` loop:

```c
    my_strg[length] = '\0'; // "length" will already point to one-beyond-the-end
```

EDIT: To address the very good points made by [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) in the comments section, you could (should) improve your `while` loop control to: (a) prevent buffer overflow and (b) handle input error conditions. Something like this:

```c
while ((length < MAXSIZE - 1) && (temp = getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF) {
    //..
```

but the exact tests and controls you use would depend on how you wish to handle such issues.

Comment: What if a 120-char string is entered? What if Ctrl+d is pressed to terminate input? Your initialization is correct, but can also be `char my_strg[MAX_SIZE] = "";` which makes the use as a string apparent.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is `scanf`. `scanf` only reads until whitespace is encountered. To fix this, you can use `fgets` (and `strcspn` to remove the newline):

```
if(fgets(my_strg, sizeof(my_strg), stdin) == NULL)
{
    perror("fgets");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
my_strg[strcspn(my_strg, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Or with `scanf`...

```
if(scanf("%99[^\n]", my_strg) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "scanf() failed to read\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

After these changes you can entirely remove your `getchar` loop.

In your program you need to check for I/O errors. I've shown you how to do this above. If you don't do this, your program could give incorrect output or in certain cases cause undefined behavior (which usually results in a crash).

Bonus: here's how to reverse a string:

```
size_t l = strlen(my_strg) / 2;
char *s = my_strg, *e = s + l;
while(l--)
{
    char tmp = *--e;
    *e = *s;
    *s++ = tmp;
}
```

Comment: A stern scolding for the OP failing to ***check the return*** of the user input function would also be informative and good examples of the proper way to validate the return of `fgets()` and `scanf()` helpful. (it seems he is missing that concept). Very good choice with `fgets()`. Always driving home the point that you cannot properly use any user input function without ***checking the return*** helps cement the learning for new C programmers.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sure. There you go.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, `scanf("%s", my_strg)` reads a string until the first white space (and a blank counts as white space). So `"Hello world"` will be read until the first blank, i.e. `my_strg` will contain `"Hello"` then. To read until a new line (including the newline), use `fgets`.

BTW: variable `length` is uninitialized, such that you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: The OP seems to know that `scanf` doesn't read the entire line … that's what the following `getchar` loop is for.

Comment: I just removed the entire scanf line and the code seems to work fine for any strings over 8 char long. If it is less than 8 char the rest of the string is printed as random symbols e.g. "A" is printed as "A©?ïvý■`"

Comment: That's because you have both `length` and your `my_strg` array *unitialized* - so there will be pseudo-random data in those variables, and anything can happen (undefined behaviour).